# c# parallel IO Completion Ports

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, io-completion-ports

I'm trying to figure out the best way to wait for some number of I/O Completion ports to complete.

For this scenario, let's say that I'm in a MVC3 web app. (My understanding is the use of I/O Completion ports here is recommended so I can return the original thread back to IIS to service other requests)

Lets say I have an array of IDs and I want to fetch an object for each ID from some network call.

What is the best way to parallelize this synchronous method?

```
   public class MyController: Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<int> ids)
       {
            ids.Select(id => _context.CreateQuery<Order>("Orders")
                                     .First(o => o.id == id));
            DataServiceQuery<Order> query = _context.CreateQuery<Order>("Orders");
            return Json(query);
       }

       private DataServiceContext _context; //let's ignore how this would be populated
   }
```

I know it would start like this:

```
   public class MyController: AsyncController
   {
       public void IndexAsync(IEnumerable<int> ids)
       {
            // magic here...

            AsyncManager.Sync(() => AsyncManager.Parameters["orders"] = orders);
       }

       public ActionResult IndexCompleted(IEnumerable<Order> orders)
       {
            return Json(orders);
       }

       private DataServiceContext _context; //let's ignore how this would be populated
   }
```

Should I be using [DataServiceContext.BeginExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646724.aspx) Method?  [DataServiceContext.BeginExecuteBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.beginexecutebatch.aspx) ?  The data service I'm consuming can only get one record at a time (this is beyond my control) and I want these individual queries to run in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

This is the pattern I've ended up using for running a batch of async operations inside MVC3:

```
public class MyController: AsyncController
   {
       public void IndexAsync(int[] ids)
       {
            var orders = new Orders[ids.Length];
            AsyncManager.Parameters["orders"] = orders;

            // tell the async manager there are X operations it needs to wait for
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment(ids.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++){
               var index = i; //<-- make sure we capture the value of i for the closure

               // create the query
               var query = _context.CreateQuery<Order>("Orders");

               // run the operation async, supplying a completion routine
               query.BeginExecute(ar => {
                   try {
                       orders[index] = query.EndExecute(ar).First(o => o.id == ids[index]);
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex){
                       // make sure we send the exception to the controller (in case we want to handle it)
                       AsyncManager.Sync(() => AsyncManager.Parameters["exception"] = ex);
                   }
                   // one more query has completed
                   AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
               }, null);
            }
       }

       public ActionResult IndexCompleted(Order[] orders, Exception exception)
       {
            if (exception != null){
                throw exception; // or whatever else you might like to do (log, etc)
            }
            return Json(orders);
       }

       private DataServiceContext _context; //let's ignore how this would be populated
   }
```

Comment: Did you enable [`AsynchronousProcessing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.asynchronousprocessing.aspx) on the connection string for the context?

Answer (score 0):

Using TPL is easy.

```
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var result = ids.AsParallel()
      .Select(id => GetOrder(id))
      .ToList();
    return Json(result);
}

Order GetOrder(int id) { ... }
```

Comment: That will run some number of threads and will still block the IIS thread.